# React Router 4 relative paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

So I'm struggling to get this simple situation working for me in React Router 4. Basically, I have a param used to retrieve user data that will render a component `/:user`. I also have a few more specific views on that page that renders like so `/:user/:specificView`.To prevent the latter to miss match users like specificViews I've been trying the following regex but nothing seems to be working right.

```
<div>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="*/:user/:specificView(coolview|niceview|okview)"
        render={routerProps =>
          <SpecificViewContainer {...routerProps} {...this.props}/>}/>
      <Route
        path="/:user"
        render={routerProps =>
          <UserPageContainer {...routerProps} {...this.props}/>}/>
    </Switch>
</div>
```

The relative paths part comes in where these two routes can sit on top of anything(`/coolusers/:user/:specificView`, `/okusers/butnotbad/:users/:specificView`... etc), so they need to be the final pieces of the pathname.

I've googled a lot and it seems the relative path format `:user/:specificView` where the opening slash is omitted was proposed but it is not working so I don't believe it made it in: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5127

Any help would be great! Unfortunately, I'm stuck with the relative path thing because I never know what the serverside view route is going to be.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using `match.path` to allow routes to be used from various parent routes:

```
   <Route 
    exact 
    strict 
    path={`${match.path}/create`} 
    component={CreateComponent} />
```